# How to deactivate a rule in sonarqube commercial?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube developer's edition and i cannot see any options to deactivate a active rule  in any quality profile as there was in basic version.
Can anyone please give me an idea as to to deactivate any active rule while using sonarqube commercial?
Thanks

Comment: There should be no difference between the editions for this aspect.

Comment: Do you try to modify `built-in` profiles?

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit built in profiles. Probably what you want to do is

- create a new profile, say P1
- set it as the default
- copy into it the rules from the profile you *have been* using
- edit (add/delete/update) the rules in P1 to meet your needs

Alternately, 'P1' could *inherit* from Sonar way, but then you wouldn't be able to *remove* rules that were added by inheritance, only edit (presumably downgrade) their severities. You would still be able to add new rules and then subsequently remove those rules you had added directly.

Comment: Can I deactivate a rule in new profile P1 or just can downgrade the severity of a rule?

Comment: See my expansions @RehanHaque.